# Get Instagram referral profile/user's name in Google Universal Analytics or GA4

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

Is there a way to find out which exactly Instagram user was a referral for session/conversion in Google Analytics (preferably Google Analytics 4)? I've have tried to explore all reports but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's in the referrer path, you can't. I'm not sure how Instagram operates, but all you get is their referrer. The referrer always exclude the query string when the origin uses an encrypted protocol.

What you can do is have them use query parameters to attribute traffic to people.